# Javascript to open email via outlook express

Tags: javascript, html, email, outlook

For open mail via Outlook I used:

```
function OpenNewMail(imgName) 
{
   var objO = new ActiveXObject('Outlook.Application');
   var objNS = objO.GetNameSpace('MAPI');
   var mItm = objO.CreateItem(0);
   mItm.Display();
   mItm.To = "";
   mItm.Subject = "My Subject";
   mItm.HTMLBody = "<html><body>MyHTML</body></html>"
   mItm.GetInspector.WindowState = 2;
}
```

Is there such a code to open mail with **Outlook Express**
*(The body of the message must be HTML)*

**My browser run with strong privilege, so i can execute any shell command**

Comment: If you use `mailto` on your links they will open in default mail reader.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot chose which application should open the email link. That's up to the browser to decide which is the default mail reader.

```
<a href="mailto:foobar@example.com">click here to send email</a>
```

On click if the Outlook express is the default mail client it will then open. Otherwise another will open, but that's what you want. If your user was using firebird instead of outlook and you could actually force the browser to open outlook, what would be the purpose?

Comment: My browser run with strong privilege, so i can execute any shell command.